# Is it possible for a server to treat a postback as not a postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Currently I have a site that loads everything on initial load (when it's not a postback).  Then it proceeds to load more data that should be fine to load regardless if it's postback or not.  I thought everytime the page is refreshed or the button is pressed there is a postback.  What I thought that if the user doesn't go to another page, any action he takes will be a postback.

However I'm getting very inconsistent errors when the site is actually on a server and was curious if perhaps, when clicking a button after a bit of inactivity, will the server possibly forget about the previous activity and treat the action as the person hitting the site for the first time again?

Below is how the button is defined....

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default controls" ID="btnAddAdditionalCom" runat="server" Text="Add Comment" OnClick="btnAddAdditionalCom_Click"/>
```

Comment: Due to authentication expiry?

Comment: You could have an auto-logon after a Session has timed out. Not sure exactly how that shows on the page.

Comment: Are you saying the user clicks the button and when you get into the `Page_Load` the `IsPostback` property is set to `false`?

Comment: @The Solution: Yeah that's what appears to be occurring,  but not every time.  It's inconsistently seeming to do that every so often and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any asp:button click will cause a postback to the server because asp is a server side language so it has to talk to the server to execute the button click. If you want to do button clicks without talking to the server use something like javascript

Comment: I don't mind that it causes a postback, but is there ever a case where you hit the button and the postback value is false?  (perhaps after the server believes you are disconnected?)  The webpage is loadbalanced on 2 servers, so perhaps that might also play a factor in this?

Comment: Hmm, why? Can you tell me why it might matter? To answer your question I don't think so.

Comment: Essentially in my code, I have an if statement where if(!IsPostBack) a bunch of initializations of datasets and other fun things.  Which works fine on first load,  however if the user starts doing things, and then that initialization happens again, it screws up all the data that used to exist and causes server errors to occur.

Comment: put your initialization code in the PageLoad method, with the if(!Postback), the button click wont touch it there

Comment: Ended up being a different problem after all that I just fully identified,  will submit a new question for it but this answer is very sufficient for what I was initially looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant modify it.

Because this is a essential concepts in asp.net.

Even you cant change the value of `IsPostback` Property (It has no setter).

If you want to treat Postback as page load then u forgot the need of `IsPostback`